# Installing in miniconda `torchvision==0.4.1` and `pytorch==1.3.0`

Tags: conda

I am trying to install `torchvision==0.4.1` and `pytorch==1.3.0` in a virtual conda environment. After I write `conda install pytorch==1.3.0 torchvision==0.4.1 -c pytorch` the following response occurs.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): / WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.7.1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.7.1
done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.9.0.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.9.0
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.6.0.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.6.0
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.8.0.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.8.0
done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - torchvision==0.4.1
  - pytorch==1.3.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

If someone can explain the warnings, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't use either packages, but it looks like the version of those packages do not exist.  (Perhaps they used to exist, but now, no longer exist.)  See [here](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/torchvision/files) for the versions of `torchvision`.  As you can see, `0.4.1` does not exist.  Why do you need those specific versions?  If you are following installation instructions from somewhere, they might be out of date.  This is for [pytorch](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files).  `1.3.0` is also too old, at least from the default channels.